# Transform array [object, object ...] to json

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

Here I have an array with object: (array can have N number of objects...)

```
[Object, Object]
  0: Object
    0: "2"
    1: "Laza Lazic"
    id_tabele: "2"
    naziv: "Laza Lazic"
__proto__: Object
 1: Object
    0: "1"
    1: "Pera Peric"
    id_tabele: "1"
    naziv: "Pera Peric"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

How I can convert this array of object to this format with javascript (jquery):

```
[{"id":"1","ime_prezime":"Pera Peric"},{"id":"2","ime_prezime":"Laza Lazic"}]
```

so `id_tabele` from array object is `id` in json, and `naziv` is `ime_prezime` in json...

Comment: also '0' is id, '1' is ime_prezime ...

Answer (score 1):

Use [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map)

```
var array = $.map(oldarray, function (obj) {
    return {
        id: obj.id_tabele,
        naziv: obj.ime_prezime
    };
})
```

Comment: i dont get json in this format: [{"id":"1","ime_prezime":"Pera Peric"},{"id":"2","ime_prezime":"Laza Lazic"}]

Comment: with JSON.strigify i get this: [{"0":"2","1":"Laza Lazic","id_tabele":"2","naziv":"Laza Lazic"},{"0":"1","1":"Pera Peric","id_tabele":"1","naziv":"Pera Peric"}]  but this is not what i need